# Reverse Find pointer to nth occurrence of a character in cstring

Tags: c++, string, bstr

How to Reverse Find pointer to nth occurrence of a character in cstring/BSTR?

```
char * RFindNthOccurrence(char* src, char t, int n)
{
   //for i/p string src = "HI,There,you,All"
   // and t =','
   // n =2
   //returned pointer should be at ",you,All" in same unchanged string
}
```

I've found first and last occurrence searching, but without modifying string reverse finding nth occurrence is problem.

Comment: What is the code you have to find the first occurrence?  You should just have to add a counter to it to keep going until you see then nth occurrence.

Comment: Find the end of the string and go back while counting.

Comment: Are you trying to reverse find nth occurrence from the beginning or nth occurrence from the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
#include <iostream>

const char * RFindNthOccurrence( const char *s, char c, size_t n )
{
    if ( !n ) return NULL;

    while ( ( n -= *s == c ) && *s ) ++s;

    return n == 0 ? s : NULL;
}

char * RFindNthOccurrence( char *s, char c, size_t n )
{
    if ( !n ) return NULL;

    while ( ( n -= *s == c ) && *s ) ++s;

    return n == 0 ? s : NULL;
}

int main() 
{
    const char *s1 = "HI,There,you,All";

    std::cout << RFindNthOccurrence( s1, ',', 2 ) << std::endl;

    char s2[] = "HI,There,you,All";

    std::cout << RFindNthOccurrence( s2, ',', 2 ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
,you,All
,you,All
```

The function behaves the same way as standard C function `strchr` that is it finds the terminating zero character but only in case when n = 1.

Another example

```
#include <iostream>

const char * RFindNthOccurrence( const char *s, char c, size_t n )
{
    if ( !n ) return NULL;

    while ( ( n -= *s == c ) && *s ) ++s;

    return n == 0 ? s : NULL;
}

char * RFindNthOccurrence( char *s, char c, size_t n )
{
    if ( !n ) return NULL;

    while ( ( n -= *s == c ) && *s ) ++s;

    return n == 0 ? s : NULL;
}

int main() 
{
    const char *s = "HI,There,you,All";
    const char *p = s;

    for ( size_t i = 1; p = RFindNthOccurrence( s, ',', i ); ++i )
    {
        std::cout << i << ": " << p << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1: ,There,you,All
2: ,you,All
3: ,All
```

The same you could do using standard C function `strchr` without writing a special function. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    const char *s = "HI,There,you,All";
    const char *p = s;
    size_t n = 2;

    while ( ( p = std::strchr( p, ',' ) ) && --n ) ++p;

    if ( n == 0 ) std::cout << p << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
,you,All
```

If you need indeed the reverse search then the function can look like in this demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

const char * RFindNthOccurrence( const char *s, char c, size_t n )
{
    if ( !n ) return NULL;

    const char *p = s + std::strlen( s );

    while ( ( n -= *p == c ) && p != s ) --p;

    return n == 0 ? p : NULL;
}

int main() 
{
    const char *s = "HI,There,you,All";
    const char *p = s;

    for ( size_t i = 1; p = RFindNthOccurrence( s, ',', i ); ++i )
    {
        std::cout << i << ": " << p << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this case the program output is

```
1: ,All
2: ,you,All
3: ,There,you,All
```

Comment: The first `main` function has a potential bug if `I` starts with `0`.  You will not print anything.

Comment: @John Smith  I do not see any bug. I wrote that the function behaves the same way as strchr that is it finds the terminating zero.

Comment: That is why I said "potential" if you start `i`  from zero inside the for loop.

Comment: @John Smith  You can write the loop as you like whether i will start from 0 or from 1. This has nothing common with the function itself.

Comment: Thanks Vlad and John. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

How about this

```
// assume n > 0
char * RFindNthOccurrence(char * str, char t, int n) {
    int count = 0;
    char *res = NULL;
    while (str) {
       if (t == *str){
        ++count; 
        if (count >= n) {
            res = str;
       }
       ++str;
    }
    return res;
}
```